# How do I slow this fill algorithm so the user can see the images being filled gradually?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, mfc, win32gui

I have tried to use `sleep()` in conjunction with `Redraw()` but this causes the program to crash. The `FLOOD_FINISHED` message causes a call to `Redraw()`

```
void Redraw()
{
    InvalidateRect(g_hWnd, NULL, FALSE);
    UpdateWindow(g_hWnd);
}
void FloodFillUtil(CDIB32* scr, int xPos, int yPos)
{
    //using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    if (IsValid(scr, xPos, yPos))
    {
        //Redraw();
        scr->SetRGB(xPos, yPos, 255, 0, 0);
        FloodFillUtil(scr, xPos + 1, yPos);
        FloodFillUtil(scr, xPos - 1, yPos);
        FloodFillUtil(scr, xPos, yPos + 1);
        FloodFillUtil(scr, xPos, yPos - 1);
    }
    return;
}

void FloodFill(CDIB32* scr, CPoint& mid)
{
    int xPos = mid.x;
    int yPos = mid.y;
    FloodFillUtil(scr, xPos, yPos);
}
void SetupDoItThread()
{
    std::thread Worker(DoIt);
    Worker.join();
}


void SetupDogThreads(CPoint mid) 
{
    //Redraw();
    FloodFill(&m_screenDib, mid);
}

void DoIt()
{
    if (!m_done)
    {
        CPoint mid;
        std::vector<std::thread> threads;
        for (int i = 0; i < REZ * REZ; ++i)
        {
            CPoint mid;
            GetBlobMidPoint(i, mid);
            threads.push_back(std::thread(SetupDogThreads, mid));
        }
        for (auto& th : threads)
        {
            th.join();
        }
        ::PostMessage(g_hWnd, FLOOD_FINISHED, NULL, NULL);
        m_done = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use ```std::sleep_for``` and also make sure your program does not terminate while the thread is busy. It looks like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48758714/how-to-sleep-a-thread-in-c to me.

Comment: I need to redraw every time a pixel changes colour in order to show a gradual flood in conjunction with a sleep function. When I attempt to call `redraw()` within my `FloodFillUtil` the program crashes.

Comment: Also tried to add `std::this_thread::sleep_for(1ms)` to `FloodFillUtil` this also caused a crash.

Comment: Re, "...causes the program to crash." Is there an error message? What does the error message say? If you are asking for help to understand what an error message means, you'll get better help by including the text of the message in your question.

Comment: There is no error message or output from the console at all. I should have probably used the word "freeze" instead of crash, my bad. I know that's nothing to go on, that's why I'm here and not googling error messages. Could there perhaps be an issue with using `std::thread` and the fact im not using  : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-threads ?

Comment: It's hard to know what your code really does without seeing missing functions like IsValid. Is it possible you could have two threads fighting each other to fill pixels, each one considering the other one's fill as being valid to overwrite? Presumably when your program is "frozen" it's really just waiting to join all your threads. Could a delay possibly introduce timing variations which mean two or more threads never end? Did you try using the debugger to see what state the program is in when it's "frozen" ?

Comment: So just to elaborate the code is supposed to iterate through a grid of 25 images. It finds the midpoint of each one and then fills it red. IsValid gets the color of a pixel and returns true if it's white and false if it's red or black. The aim is to have each image flood filled using its own thread, but gradually so that the user can see it being filled. When I put a breakpoint at redraw each thread loops through it sequentially by the looks of things.

Comment: You are mixing drawing in worker- & GUI-thread!?

Comment: How is the CDIB32 bitmap drawn onto the window? You call `InvalidateRect()/UpdateWindow()` but that's all we can see. Imo redrawing the whole window to only draw a pixel is an overkill, aren't there other ways to do it? Winows GDI for example has the `SetPixel()` function (sorry, don't know about win32gui). Also, using pixel-level recursion isn't really good; it could easily be changed to an iterative implementation.

Comment: I'm passing invalidateRect a pointer to a rect containing the images, pixel is being set with SetRGB. InvalidateRect is  wm_paint message

Comment: From what I can find on the web SetRGB() sets a pixel in the bitmap's buffer - I could even find its code. But the bitmap has to be drawn on the window or a control. How is that done? I guess in WM_PAINT (or OnDraw() or OnPaint()). Pls make this part of your code available. What is g_hWnd? How is it associated with the bitmap?